# How to prove that the marginals of the limit distribution are the limits of the marginals of a sequence of measures?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Suppose $(\pi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of measures on two Polish spaces $X$ and $Y$, each with marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$. I want to prove that if it exists, the limit of the sequence, denoted $\pi$, has marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$ also. I use the following definition of weak convergence:

A sequence of measures $(\mu_n)$ in $\mathcal{M}$ is said to converge weakly to a measure $\mu \in \mathcal{M}$ if 
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{n \to \infty}\int \lvert f \rvert \ d\mu_n = \int \lvert f \rvert \ d\mu
\end{align*}
for all Lipschitz continuous, bounded functions $f$.

Proof:
There exists a sequence $(f_n)$ of Lipschitz continuous bounded functions increasing to $\mathbb{1}_E$ where $E = A \times Y$ for all measurable $A \subset X$. Hence (applying Monotone Convergence theorem):

$\pi(A \times E) = lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}\int f_j \ d\pi = lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int f_j \ d\pi_n $

I want to be able to exchange the two limits to complete my argument and show that the marginals are equal. However I am not sure how to argue this (or if it is even true).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: A bit nitpicking: I guess $\pi_n$ is a sequence of probability measures on the *product space* $X \times Y$. Moreover, Polish spaces need not be equipped with a prescribed metric, so the notion of Lipschitz function need not make sense in the first place. Finally, even in $\mathbb{R}$, there are Borel sets for which the indicator function cannot be approximated pointwise by sequence of continuous functions.

Comment: Okay thanks! This is the kind of nitpicking that I needed. Do you know of a result that does what I am trying to do? I.e.  shows that the marginals of the limit are the limit of the marginals?

Comment: As for the proof, let $f$ be any continuous bounded function on $X$. Then the tensor product $f \otimes 1$, defined by $(f\otimes 1)(x, y) = f(x)$, is continuous and bounded on $X\times Y$. So by weak convergence, $$ \int_{X\times Y}(f \otimes 1) \, \mathrm{d}\pi_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int_{X\times Y} (f\otimes 1) \, \mathrm{d}\pi.$$ Now, your assumption tells that $\int_{X\times Y}(f \otimes 1) \, \mathrm{d}\pi_n = \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu$. So, if $\pi_X$ denotes the $X$-marginal of $\pi$, then $\int_X f\mathrm{d}\pi_X=\int_X f\mathrm{d}\mu$ for all such $f$, which tells $\pi_X=\mu$.